# How to list all items in a directory in powershell

Tags: powershell, directory-listing

How to list all items - both regular and hidden - in powershell using `Get-ChildItem`?

Just `Get-ChildItem` doesn't list hidden items. `Get-ChildItem -Hidden` lists only hidden items.

Something like `ls -a` from Linux world would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `Force` for example

`Get-ChildItem -Force`